# I need to make a graph in python turtle with 100000 points to plot

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I have to make a python turtle line graph with a 100000 points. I don't need any numbers on the x or y axis. All of the y axis positions are in a list called C_txt_list. So far I have got some code that prints each value in C_txt_list. The C_txt_list is only values from 0 to 100.

```
# re-opens Rand_Numbers but the complete version and in read mode

C_txt = open("Rand_Numbers", "r")

# reads each line of C_txt and adds it to a list

with C_txt as File:

    C_txt_list = C_txt.readlines()

C_txt_list = [lines.strip() for lines in C_txt_list]

# prints each element in C_txt_list

index_Num = 0

while index_Num != repeats:

    print(C_txt_list[index_Num])

    index_Num += 1
```

I also need the graph to fit on a window 1500p by 800p. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a crude example that should do what you describe:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(1500, 800)
screen.screensize(100_000, 800)
screen.tracer(False)

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.hideturtle()
turtle.penup()

with open("Rand_Numbers") as file:
    for x, line in enumerate(file, start=-50_000):
        y = int(line)  # int() deals with the whitespace/newline

        turtle.goto(x, y)
        turtle.pendown()  # needed after 1st point

screen.tracer(True)
screen.exitonclick()
```

[image]

Note the scroll bar at the bottom of the window to view the rest of the "data" which I wrote this code to generate:

```
from random import randint

with open("Rand_Numbers", 'w') as file:
    for x in range(100_000):
        y = randint(0, 100)
        print(y, file=file)
```

**ASIDE**

This problem turned up an annoying glitch in Python turtle.  I wanted to enumerate the data starting from 0, not -50,000 so I tried to modify the coordinate system to match the data:

```
screen.setup(1500, 800)
screen.setworldcoordinates(0, -400, 1500, 400)
screen.screensize(100_000, 800)
```

However, by their implementation, `screensize()` undoes the work of `setworldcoordinates()` and `setworldcoordinates()` undoes the work of `screensize()`.  So no matter what order you call them in, this doesn't work!