# Turtle setworldcoordinates and window/canvas sizing

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I am new to Python and Stackoverflow but have previous general programming experience.  I have Python 3.7 installed on Windows 11 and using Pyscripter as a development tool, display device is 1600 x 900 pixels.

I want to develop simple examples of visualising cartesian based fractal functions that the target audience can see how the fractal develops and change some parameters – hence adopting Turtle rather than more technical packages.

I am trying to understand how `screensize()`, `setup()` and especially `setworldcoordinates()` interact when using Turtle graphics.  I found the examples at the link https://www.programmersought.com/article/38514262202/ helpful but am puzzled by some outputs in the following code, but have not delved into the underlying Tkinter yet.
The following code snippets and outputs illustrates my question.

```
import turtle as tu
tu.setup(400, 400)
tu.screensize(800, 800, bg='lightblue')
tu.setworldcoordinates(-1, -1, 5, 5)  # Custom coordinate system
tu.goto(0, 0)
print("screensize is ",tu.screensize())
print("window size is ",tu.window_width(), tu.window_height())
tu.mainloop()
```

```
*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized ***
screensize is  (380, 380)
window size is  400 400
```

Reading the Python documentation I understand the initial `screensize()` assignment has been reset by `setworldcoordinates()` but not sure where the (380, 380) is derived from rather than (400,300) default. Can this be changed?

I also understood that `setworldcoordinates()` acted on the screensize “canvas”.  However, in the code above, increasing `tu.screensize` to (2000,20000) had no effect on the output but then changing `tu.setup` to (800,800) gave the following output, changing both values.

```
*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized ***
screensize is  (780, 780)
window size is  800 800
```

Can anyone explain why changing `setup()` parameters appears to affect  both screensize and window size when using `setworldcoordinates`?

Comment: See the aside in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59526171/5771269) which notes that `screensize()` and `setworldcoordinates()` don't play nicely together.

Answer (score 0):

In response to my own question I think I now know the answer.  The following code snippet helps illustrate the solution:

```
import turtle as tu

#Define size of display window
tu.setup(800, 800)

#Define size of drawing screen/canvas and colour
tu.screensize(400, 400, bg='lightblue')

tu.setworldcoordinates(-1, -1, 5, 5)  # Custom coordinate system

print("screensize is ",tu.screensize())
print("window size is ",tu.window_width(), tu.window_height())

tu.mainloop()
```

The snippet above produced the following output:

```
*** Remote Interpreter Reinitialized ***
screensize is  (780, 780)
window size is  800 800
>>>
```

Changing the `tu.screensize()` parameters in the above code to `200,200` and leaving the `tu-setup()` parameters unchanged did not change the output.
Looking at the following code fragment from `setworldcoordinates()`  function in the Turtle graphics module:

```
if self.mode() != "world":
    self.mode("world")
xspan = float(urx - llx)
yspan = float(ury - lly)
wx, wy = self._window_size()
self.screensize(wx-20, wy-20)
```

The penultimate line assigns the variables wx and wy to the width and height of the Turtle window as defined under setup() function, NOT the screen (canvas), but does not change the underlying parameters of the window.

The last line assigns the values of wx and wy, -20, derived from the window size to change the screensize (canvas).

This would explain why the screensize is always 20 pixels less than the window size and why changes to the screensize are ignored by the setworldcoordinates() function.